# What This Path Mean?

Tags: php

I'm Studding basic PHP and I don't understand this line of code:

```
define('App_Path',$root . 'app' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Comment: Your creating a global [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). Its like a variable but the value will never change. App_Path is the name of the constant.

Comment: In addition bear in mind that contants or Constants you can only define them once and can not change them later like variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a named constant known as `App_Path`

For DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR - in different OS there is different directory separator. In Windows it's \ in Linux it's /. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR is constant with that OS directory separator. So in the code, you are defining a named constant known as App_Path , as $root . 'app' . '/' (or '' in Win OS)

So, if you use the following code

```
<?php

$root='ken';
define('App_Path',$root . 'app' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

?>
```

the constant App_Path will be kenapp/ (in linux) and kenapp\ (in Win OS)

See this Sandbox
https://onlinephp.io/c/d80c2

BTW, please note that usually the constant name is in UPPPERCASE letters such as APP_PATH instead of App_Path, which is:

```
define('APP_PATH',$root . 'app' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

For further details on defining a named constant , please visit the following page

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php